# Less expensive version of `sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n`

Tags: awk, performance, sort, uniq

I have an unsorted list of IPs that I need to count and sort by occurrences.
I use `sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n` and that works well, but I'd like something less expensive... surely `awk` can do this?

#### Input

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
1.1.1.1
3.3.3.3
2.2.2.2
1.1.1.1
```

#### Output

```
3 1.1.1.1
2 2.2.2.2
1 3.3.3.3
```

Comment: post some input fragment and expected result

Comment: This is likely to be less expensive than the awk accumulator solution unless there is a huge proportion of duplicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With single **awk** process:

```
awk '{ a[$1]++ }END{ for(i in a) print a[i],i }' file
```

The output:

```
3 1.1.1.1
2 2.2.2.2
1 3.3.3.3
```

---

To output records sorted by number of occurrences in descending order use the following GNU **awk** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc" }{ a[$1]++ }
     END{ for(i in a) print a[i],i }' file
```

Comment: that won't do the final sort by the number of hits, but just gives the output in the order awk happens to give the keys

Comment: @ilkkachu, see my update